# why I encounter "The import org.springframework cannot be resolved" though I install gradle and add dependencies

Tags: java, spring

I go this website https://start.spring.io and download my first java web application. Then I run gradle build. Unfortunately, I get these errors[image]
This is my gradle file, it seems that I have already added dependencies. I don't know why I still get the errors "The import org.springframework cannot be resolved"?
[image]

The following picture shows my folder structure
[image]

Can anyone help my fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to reimport the project. Does it work from command line? Try to run `./gradlew clean bootRun`.

Comment: Then I get these errors: which errors? You're not showing us the result of your gradle build. So, if the build passes, and eclipse has errors, it means it's an eclipse issue. You need to properly import the project as a gradle project.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I reimport the project as a gradle project, and it works